# Are you able to use Okta with mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, okta

Are you able to use okta with MySQL? I know you use okta to securely store user accounts, but I also wanna use an Id for the users on my own database

Comment: I don't know - does Okta support an external IdP; that's what you're asking. Could try searching that.

Answer (score 2):

If your question is, can I store Custom User information in my own database and just use Okta for storing authentication information?

For sure. I do it all the time with PostGreSQL. I just use the Okta user id as a way to link my DB's user information with the Okta user. Then when you authenticate, you can get the user's Okta ID from the token to fetch other information you want to store locally.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong. You create an app with okta and node.js, you authenticate with okta and the user credentials that you use to log in are store in the okta database, once you log in okta gives you a token (meaning everything is correct and your able to log in and log out) you use the user id that is returned with the token and you save that to your SQL database so you can add additional information or a way to use that id to use it however you wan and that's how you can link okta with your own database?